# Why finger is bend other direction

Tags: rigging

Why the finger bending to side. I try to search for the roll the bone but did not understood which axis to match to make bend the finger. I want to make punch pose of the hand. Any suggestion where its going wrong or how it will work. Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: if you are saying that your finger is not going in the axis in reference of ur character then you can press x,y or z according to which ever axis you want to move press the axis button 2 times in order to move ur finger in reference of ur character

Comment: your armature is a bit complex, I got lost with all these bone layers, but maybe you need to correct a bone orientation in Edit mode...